# How does fminunc optimise the learning rate (step proportion) value in gradient descent?

Tags: c, matlab, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I currently work on a machine learning algorithm and I noticed that when I use Matlab's `fminunc` the algorithm converges to the global minimum very fast (few iterations) comparing to when I manually update the parameters:

`thetas[j] = thetas[j] - (alpha*gradient)/sampleNum;`

I think it's because I naively presume `alpha` (step proportion) to be constant.

So, how does one implement something like `fminunc` in C?

I tried to start with a large `alpha` and adjust it if the current cost turns out to be larger than the previous cost. The problem with this comes when the shape of the minimised function is not linear, since `alpha` can get a very small value initially and fail to return to a larger one when the function shape tends to become 'flat' (and larger steps could be taken).

Comment: Matlab's `fminunc` doesn't use gradient descent. It uses quasi-Newton methods, which can be significantly faster, no matter how you control the step size.

Comment: @3lectrologos thanks for the insight. That would explain why I get very good results for quadratic functions when using `fminunc`. So, maybe I should try to use a different method instead improving my `alpha` guessing. From your experience, using quasi-Newton methods has any downsides compared with gradient descent (except that, it's probably harder to implement)

Comment: I'm probably not the right person to answer this, but I think there are some implementation details in Newton-like methods that may be somewhat tricky if you try to implement them from scratch (e.g. numerical issues). In terms of performance, I don't know of a reason to prefer gradient descent, except if your problem is really large (see stochastic gradient descent).

Comment: Since your first comment somehow answers my question (I was wrong to assume `fminunc` uses gradient descent and probably improving my step size guessing won't take me to the right direction) could you convert it to an answer so I can accept it. I'll study further the quasi-Newton methods. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab's `fminunc` doesn't actually use gradient descent, but rather Newton-like methods ([BFGS-based quasi-Newton or trust-region](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/unconstrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html) depending on the problem size), which are in general significantly faster than gradient descent, no matter how you choose the step size.

Maybe you should look into this kind of methods if you want faster convergence.